# Is there any better way of writing SQL Insert statement with Java Prepared statements

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I have an insert query which is having more than 150 columns in it and I will be inserting data based on certain conditions so any better way of writing the query using prepared statements in java.

Some of the data can be null as well.

```
stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

stmt.setObject(1,id);
stmt.setObject(2,date);
.
.
.
.
.
stmt.setObject(n,someotherfield);
```

Comment: don't use java?  But having 150 columns is going to cause you trouble some time.

Comment: If you have a database table with 150 columns, I would suggest you redesign your database.  It's not normal to have so many.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem if a framework itself has that many then I think you cant change it if you want the framework to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

For most datatypes, `setObject` should do the trick (as you've already used in your question). You could hold a list of values and loop over it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < valuesList.size(); ++i) {
    stmt.setObject(i + 1, valuesList.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Probably not much better, because you then you have to build the `valueList`, moving the same kind of repetition to `valueList.add(id); valueList.add(date); valueList.add(someotherfield);`.  I'd at least use a `Map[String, Object]` to maintain some readability thanks to named columns `valueMap.put("id", id);` That `valueMap` could then also be used to build up the SQL statement string (and maybe nulls can be skipped entirely if the column schema has defined defaults).

Comment: @Mureinik thank you for the answer just like what #thilo said its again the same extra work what I am looking for is any other way except putting the columns in a list or map etc and then again looping over that but anyway thank you